# Vue, Access variables from index.html-script in mounted

Tags: javascript, vue.js, paypal

I have to run an external script in my Vue.js Application (If it is of interest, it is a script to run the Paypal Smart Buttons). I added the script in the index.html file.

Now I want to access the variable "paypal" which is defined in the script from aboce. Unfortunately, the variable is not defined in that context (mounted hook: "ReferenceError: paypal is not defined"). If I access the variable via console, it works as intended. How can I access it?

public/index.html

```
<script
    src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=SB_CLIENT_ID">
</script>
```

src/components/PaymentComponent.vue

```
<script>
export default {
 ...
  mounted() {
      paypal.Buttons().render('#paypal-button-container');
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: try to add the script before the   root div with id app

Comment: can you share your index.html